# Track a user movement

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have an Image frame containing some users. And an another again containing some users.
I am trying to find if any of the user from the first Image is also present in the second Image.

Till now, all my Image frames were continuous with time. So I have a program which keeps storing the co-ordinates of person's movements from one screen to another. Hence I could deduce who is the respective person in any frame.

How do i deal with this discrete case. Color Combination of clothes? But this can yield to many duplicates and wrong data. (If error margin is less, then no issues)

Apart from Image processing, some other means? I have seen some applications which track user movement based upon the wii-fii pings their phone emit.

I am looking for possible methods/options

Answer (score 1):

You should think how you as a human being would track a user in the discrete case. I doubt even a human will be very accurate in tracking a given person, but I believe what I would use is mostly size and colors of clothing. Keep in mind the computer only does what you teach it to do so if you are not able to perform a given task in a finite time having the same data the computer has probably the computer also will not be able to.